# Running ng test on all apps in project

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli-v6

Angular CLI: 6.0.0

new setup with CLI

with multiple projects using ng generate library

Generated 2 projects as well as a main app

However when running ng test every project is tested one by one including the main app

The problem that i want a final test which will test all the projects(library) and the main app at once

Using ng test only runs every project one by one

However when using test driven development i want to be able to do

ng test --watch

and see that the whole app is tested correctly

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward to add something to `scripts` to run each one in turn, no?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe updated the question. i want be be able to do test driven development on the whole project at once

Comment: Wouldn't the answer still be the same? You can write a package script that starts the `ng test --watch` in each of them, using something like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) as the watch processes are probably blocking

Comment: Also TDD doesn't necessarily mean continuously running all of the tests. I run the full suite regularly, but am generally more focused on the part I'm actually working on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure i run the whole test only once the unit test is done to check if there are no conflict with other dev

Comment: @Capricorn using ng test --watch create an error

Comment: So that's **not** watching. Either way, the point stands.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah guest you are right but how can i make sure that all libraries are working well together

Comment: So your concern is even if all of the unit tests pass the libraries might not all work correctly when integrated together? That's not something you can cover with unit tests, you need higher level integration and end-to-end testing (like the the e2e tests the CLI sets up with Protractor).

Answer (score 2):

There's an open issue on this ([angular/angular-cli#10765](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10765)); you might want to follow it.

---

Until this issue gets resolved, there might be a workaround using Nx, as stated in [nrwl/nx#514 (comment)](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/514#issuecomment-395990966):

> ```
> yarn affected:test --files=package.json
> ```

If you want to optimize the tests a bit, maybe the following command helps. It runs tests in parallel, retests only failed ones and – in genereal – tests only the changes you've made.

> ```
> yarn affected:test --base=master --head=HEAD --parallel --only-failed
> ```